# Importing JS modules into TS app: d.ts is not a module error

Tags: typescript

I'm new to Typescript and am trying to migrate an existing JS application into it. I'm trying to follow instructions from https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html to import JS files without having to convert them to TS (yet).

In the following file (index.tsx) I'm trying to import a JS module (sugg.js) - I don't want to convert this to TS yet, so have set up a declaration file for it (sugg.d.ts):

```
/// <reference path="../utils/sugg.d.ts"/>
import { populateSugg} from '../utils/sugg.ts';
```

However I get the following errors on this:

```
File '/utils/sugg.d.ts' is not a module.ts(2306)
```

I've set up the declaration file as below:

```
//sugg.d.ts
declare module sugg {
    export function populateSugg} (
        scope: string,
        value: string,
        property?: string
    ): string;
}
```

'sugg.js' contains the following function (among others):

```
const populateSugg = (scope, value, property) => {
    //Do things
    return updatedVal;
}

...

export {
    ...
    populateSugg
}
```

Can anyone suggest where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Try adding `export default {};` to the bottom of you declaration file.

Comment: @frankenapps Adding that gives a different error in index.tsx ('sugg.js has no exported member 'populateSugg') and sugg.d.ts then also has an error ('The expression of an export assignment must be an identifier or qualified name in an ambient context')